# Show that $\chi_A$ is continuous on $\operatorname{int}{A}$ and $A'$ but not $\partial_A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{A'}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that the characteristic function $\chi_A$ is continuous on the interior of $A$ and of its complement $A'$, but is discontinuous on the boundary $\partial_A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{A'}$

---

Thoughts:

$\chi_A(x) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    1 & \quad \text{if $x\in{A}$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{if $x\notin{A}$}
  \end{array} \right.$

After plotting the graph,

Obviously,

$\operatorname{int}{A}$ is the continuous horizontal line for all segments with $y=1$

$A'$ is the continuous horizontal line for all segments with $y=0$

for $\operatorname{int}$ and ${A'}$ must cover all possible x, how come intersection is empty????

Comment: This is false. For example, let $A=\{0\}$. Then $\chi_A(x)$ is continuous on its boundary, which is simply $A$. But perhaps you mean that $\chi_A$ has no points of continuity (as a function on $\mathbb R^n$) in $\partial_A$, which is different than not being continuous on $\partial_A$.

Comment: @AlexBecker Yes, I think Paul is like me and is not careful enough with his wording. He most likely meant the latter.

Comment: Restrict the function to the interior, that is, look into $\chi_A:\operatorname{int}A\to \{0,1\}$. I assume you endow $\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology. Then $f^{-1}(X)$ is open for any choice of $X\subseteq \{0,1\}$: it is either $\operatorname{int}(A)$ or $\varnothing$. Do the same for $\Bbb R^n\setminus \operatorname{int}(A)=\operatorname{cl}(\Bbb R^n\setminus A)$ which is closed. In any case the preimage of any open/closed set is open/closed, so you're done.

Comment: @julien Do you agree with the above?

Comment: @AlexBecker What do you think?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Yes, it works. You might want to add that the identity from $(\{0,1\}, discrete)$ to $(\mathbb{R},usual)$ is (trivially) continuous. So that the map $\chi_A$ is continuous by composition of this one and the one you considered.

Comment: Well, but the whole point of this question, I think, is to prove the restriction on each $\operatorname{int}A$ and $\operatorname{cl}(\Bbb R^n\setminus A)$ is continuous, is it not? That's what I showed. Why add the identity around?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff You want/need to show $\chi_A:int A\longrightarrow (\mathbb{R},usual)$ is continuous. You explained why $\chi_A:int A\longrightarrow \{0,1\}$ discrete is continuous. You miss the (trivial, of course) $(\{0,1,\}, discrete )\longrightarrow (\mathbb{R},usual)$ continuity of the identity to get the continuity of the initial map.

Comment: OK, I didn't interpret the question as such. Also note I read "and of its complement" as saying "the complement of the interior of $A$", but it actually says $\operatorname{int}(\Bbb R^n\setminus A)$ (the interior of the complement) which is just the open set $\Bbb R^n\setminus \operatorname{cl}(A)$ so the argument holds.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Well, actually, the OP did not say what the codomain was and what topology was on it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, here is an example in $\mathbb{R}$. Take $A=[0,1)$. Then the interior of $A$ is $(0,1)$, the interior of $A'$ is $(-\infty,0)\cup(1,+\infty)$, and the boundary is $\{0,1\}$. Note that this gives a partition of $\mathbb{R}$. If you take $A$ to be a line in the plane, then the interior of $A$ is empty, the interior of $A'$ is $A'$, and the boundary is the line $A$. Note this is again a partition of the plane.

As pointed out by AlexBecker, we need to be careful with the wording. I suppose you regard $\chi_A$ as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, equipped with the usual topology inherited from the norm/absolute value.

If a function is continuous at every point of $S\subseteq X$, then it is continuous on $S$ (good exercise on the induced topology). The converse is not true in general. For instance, $\chi_\mathbb{Z}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{Z}$, but it is discontinuous at every integer as a function on $\mathbb{R}$.

If a function is constant on $S\subseteq X$, it is easily seen to be continuous on $S$. So $\chi_A$ is continuous on the interior of $A$, and on the interior of $A'$, because it is constant there.

If a function is continuous on an open set $S\subseteq X$, then it is continuous at every point of $S$ (good exercise again). So $\chi_A$ is also continuous at every point of the interiors of $A$ and $A'$.

Now what about the boundary?

Assume that $\chi_A$ is continuous at some point $x$ of the boundary. You can use sequences. By assumption, there exist $(x_n)$ in $A$ and $(x'_n)$ in $A'$ which both converge to $x$. What is the value of $\chi_A$ on these sequences? What are these values supposed to converge to? Look for the contradiction.

Now you've shown that $\chi_A$ is discontinuous at every point of the boundary. But this does not mean it can't be continuous on the boundary.

Comment: @Paul I've edited my answer. In particular, I give you two examples at the beginning, since you seem to have a misconception of the notions of interior and boundary.